# database is locked when using SQLite3 and MPI to generate different databases

Tags: sqlite, mpi

I would like to use `SQLite3` and `MPI` to generate many databases, and different processes produce and process different databases. But when I ran the program in Linux, I got an error message that `database is locked` from `sqlite3_exec()`. I know this message means I tried to do incompatible things with a database at the same time from the same database connection. Obviously, I did not do incompatible things at the same time. The version of `SQLite3` is 3.11.0. So how to handle this situation? Thank you in advance!

Here is my simple code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int testFunc(int firstBreakPt, int secondBreakPt, char* saveFile);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    char *saveFile = "test";

    int breakPt[2][2]={{300,500},{600,900}};

    int myid, numprocs, taskNum = 2;

    int paraSent[2];

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);

    if (myid == 0)  // master;
    {
        MPI_Bcast(saveFile, sizeof(saveFile), MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for(int i =0; i<taskNum; i++)
        {
            paraSent[0] = breakPt[i][0];
            paraSent[1] = breakPt[i][1];

            MPI_Send(&paraSent[0], 2, MPI_INT, i+1, i+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    }   
    else    // slaves;
    {
        MPI_Recv(&paraSent[0], 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        int firstBreakPt, secondBreakPt;

        firstBreakPt = paraSent[0];
        secondBreakPt = paraSent[1];

        testFunc(firstBreakPt, secondBreakPt, saveFile);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

int testFunc(int firstBreakPt, int secondBreakPt, char* saveFile)
{
    // convert int to string;
    ostringstream temp1;
    temp1<<firstBreakPt;
    string firstBreakPtStr = temp1.str();

    ostringstream temp2;
    temp2<<secondBreakPt;
    string secondBreakPtStr = temp2.str();

    string fileNameTemp = saveFile; // convert char* to string;
    string fileName = fileNameTemp + "_" + firstBreakPtStr + "_" + secondBreakPtStr + ".db";

    cout<<"fileName is: "<< fileName <<endl;    

    // open a new db;
    sqlite3* dropTableDB;
    cout << "sqlite3_open("", &dropTableDB): " << sqlite3_open( fileName.c_str(), &dropTableDB) << endl;

        if(dropTableDB == 0)
        {
            printf("\nCould not open database.");
            return 1;
        }

        char *errmsg;
        int result;

        // DROP TABLE PrimaryForLateralDistribution;
        result = sqlite3_exec ( dropTableDB,
                                "Drop TABLE IF EXISTS PrimaryForLateralDistribution",  // stmt
                                0,
                                0,
                                &errmsg
                );
        if ( result != SQLITE_OK )
        {
            cout << "\nCould not prepare statement: Drop TABLE: " << result << endl;
            cout << "errmsg: " << errmsg << endl;
           return 1;
        }

}
```

Comment: Make sure no two MPI processes share the same database file name.

Comment: I am sure that different databases have different names, the output of names are test_300_500.db and test_600_900.db.